# Symfony: Can I use both JWT + oAuth to authenticate different users?

Tags: symfony, oauth-2.0, jwt

Before explain why what I need your help, just keep in mind that I am totally new on Symfony 3.4, so please be lenient with me.

What I try to create is a `RESTful API`.

For the admin section, I'd like my users to log in every day in order to access the application dashboard. I already do that, by using the `LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle` with a token that expires every 24 hours.

Then, my API will have several `client applications` that should access my data using an access token, but not using JWT. Those client applications will be mobile apps *( implemented on React Native )* and desktop apps *( implemented on Electron)*.

The way I thought I should authorize those applications to access my API is by providing them with an Authentication token using the `oAuth` protocol.

So, the basic question is, if I could config both authorization methods *( JWT + oAuth )* at the same time for the same resources.

So, for example, let's say I have the following endpoint: `/api/v1/repository/chocolates`.

With the `jms_serializer` I am able to choose what data I want to display on each group, so for a user has the `ROLE_ADMIN` I can display all the product information, while for the user has the `ROLE_SOME_GRANT` will only be possible to see the title and the description.

So is it possible to access the `/api/v1/repository/chocolates` either by using the `JWT` token my admins have or by using the `oAuth` token my client apps will have?

For the moment my `app/config/security.yml` has the following setup:

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
security:

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:         ROLE_USER
        ROLE_NUTRITIONIST:  ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN:   ROLE_ADMIN

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        oauth_token:
            pattern: ^/oauth/v2/token
            security: false

        oauth_authorize:
            pattern: ^/oauth/v2/auth
            security: false

        api_user_management:
            pattern:    ^/api/v1/user/(login|request\/reset|password\/reset)
            anonymous:  true
            stateless:  true

        api_user_management_safe:
            pattern:    ^/api/v1/user/(login|request\/reset|password\/reset)
            anonymous:  true
            stateless:  true

        api_user_login:
            pattern:    ^/api/v1/login
            stateless:  true
            anonymous:  true
            form_login:
                check_path:               /api/v1/login
                require_previous_session: false
                username_parameter:       username
                password_parameter:       password
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            logout:     true

        #############################################
        ## HERE IF I CHANGE THE fos_oauth to false
        ## I CAN ACCESS MY ENDPOINT : /api/v1/register/new/user
        ## WHILE IF THAT IS TRUE I GET THE ERROR MESSAGE:
        ##
        ## {
        ##     "error": "invalid_grant",
        ##     "error_description": "The access token provided is invalid."
        ## }
        #############################################

        api_access:
            pattern:    ^/api/v1
            stateless:  true
            #lexik_jwt:  ~
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
            fos_oauth: true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/v1/user/request/reset,                          role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api/v1/user/password/reset,                         role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        - { path: ^/api/v1/user/update,                                 role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        - { path: ^/api/v1/user/((?!request)|(?!password)|(?!update)),  role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        - { path: ^/api/v1/register/new/user,                           role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        - { path: ^/api/v1/,                                            role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

So, based on that security setup do you think there's a way to have multiple authorization services in my application?